# R packages rgdal / rgeos "is not available (for R version 3.1.1)"

Tags: r

Having difficulty installing some packages in a new R build on OSX Mavericks.  Both `rgeos` and `rgdal` return e.g.:

```
package 'rgeos' is available as a source package but not as a binary

Warning in install.packages :
  package 'rgeos' is not available (for R version 3.1.1)
```

On my windows system both packages have installed fine for R 3.1.1, so is this a Mavericks/OSX version issue or do I have an issue with my build?  Changing the library repository makes no difference.  I've looked at building from binaries, but e.g. on the [rgeos homepage](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgeos/index.html) it states "OS X Mavericks binaries: r-release: not available" so I'm snookered.

Grateful for advice.

---

Edit:

Trying the suggestion by @Andrie:

```
> install.packages('rgeos', type='source')
Installing package into ‘/Users/robinedwards/Library/R/3.1/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/src/contrib/rgeos_0.3-6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 240510 bytes (234 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 234 Kb

* installing *source* package ‘rgeos’ ...
** package ‘rgeos’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
configure: CC: clang
configure: CXX: clang++
configure: rgeos: 0.3-4
checking for /usr/bin/svnversion... yes
configure: svn revision: 450
checking geos-config usability... 
./configure: line 2056: geos-config: command not found
no
configure: error: geos-config not usable
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgeos’
* removing ‘/Users/robinedwards/Library/R/3.1/library/rgeos’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rgeos’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/_s/ppznw4sx7p51kwv__hj3d8540000gn/T/RtmpK40xj7/downloaded_packages’
```

And a screenshot of the build page:

[image]

Comment: Have you tired `install.packages(..., type="source")` ?  Also see the build page http://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_rgeos.html

Comment: Hi Andrie, please see edits above

Comment: you need to install the geos library package for OS X Maverick.

Comment: But of course. Thanks martin/Andrie together you provide the solution. Who wants a green tick?

Comment: @richie-cotton shouldn't the newer question be marked as 'duplicate'?

Comment: In this case I think that generality trumps order of creation.  I'm trying to get all info on package-not-available problems into one place.  That question is community wiki, so if you want to add anything `rgdal`/`rgeos`-specific (or anything else useful), that would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install `rgdal` and `rgeos` from source.

1. First install the package `rgeos`
2. Then install `rgdal` from source.

Try this:

```
install.packages('rgeos', type="source")
install.packages('rgdal', type="source")
```

Comment: Cheers. And for the homebrewer `brew install gdal` worked fine..

Comment: can someone explain why installing it from source works and is necessary?

Comment: I have the same problem with rgeos not being available for R.3.13 so  I have tried `install.packages('rgeos', type="source")` and 
`install.packages('rgdal', type="source")´ but these failed. Then i went to http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/ and downloaded http://download.osgeo.org/geos/geos-3.4.2.tar.bz2
In terminal i did the following which went well.
`·/configure`
`make` . But how the hell do i get the package into R: i have also tried `brew install gdal` but don't know how to get R to see the package.

Comment: Version .3-15 of `rgeos` does not install correctly -- this is from source. Install the binary which works fine (version .3-11, I believe).

Comment: this seems not to work for rgdal in R 3.2: `install.packages("rgdal", type="source")` `package ‘rgdal’ is not available (for R version 3.2.3)`

Comment: Worked out downloading `https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rgdal/rgdal_1.2-5.tar.gz` and installing it with `R CMD INSTALL rgdal_1.2-5.tar.gz`